# In Mongodb, how to retrieve the subset of an object that matches a condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

#### What I'm trying to do:

Filter a field of a collection that matches a given condition. Instead of returning every item in the field (which is an array of items), I only want to see matched items.

Similar to

```
select items from test where items.histPrices=[10,12]
```

It is also similar to what's found on the mongodb website here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

Here's what I have been trying:

```
db.test.save({"name":"record", "items":[{"histPrices":[10,12],"name":"stuff"}]})
db.test.save({"name":"record", "items":[{"histPrices":[10,12],"name":"stuff"}, 
{"histPrices":[12,13],"name":"stuff"},{"histPrices":[11,14],"name":"stuff"}]})

db.test.find({},{"name":1,"items.histPrices":[10, 12]})
```

It will return all the objects that have a match for items.histPrices:[10,12], including ALL of the items in items[]. But I don't want the ones that don't match the condition.

From the comments left on Mongodb two years ago, the solution to get only the items with that histPrices[10,12] is to do it with javascript code, namely, loop through the result set and filter out the other items.

I wonder if there's a way to do that with just the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `find` query is **wrong**

```
   db.test.find({},{"name":1,"items.histPrices":[10, 12]})
```

Your condition statement should be in the first part of the find statement.In your query `{}` means fetch all documents similar to this sql

```
   select items from test (no where clause)
```

you have to change your mongodb find to

```
   db.test.find({"items.histPrices":[10, 12]},{"name":1})
```

make it work

since your items is an array and if you wanted to return only the matching sub item, you have to use [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator)

```
  db.test.find({"items.histPrices":[10, 12]},{"name":1,'items.$':1})
```

Comment: This seems simpler and better.

Comment: Tried your queries in Try it out on Mongodb.org. First one seems right, but second one doesn't show histPrices of the matched one: [ 
  {   "name" : "record",   "items" : [   {     } ],   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "50955500cc93742e0d102047"   }   },
  {   "name" : "record",   "items" : [   {     },   {     },   {     } ],   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "5095550fcc93742e0d102048"   }   }
]

Comment: But this works on my mongodb 2.2. The web page says:"Note: this shell supports only a subset of the real shell's features." Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Yea, i tried again on my local machine. It works. The prod server is using version of 2.0.7 so this didn't work. Will upgrade to 2.2 next week.

Comment: Postional operator seems to be a v1.4+ feature, let me try again. UPDATE: It doesn't seem to work on 2.0.7 with exactly same query

Comment: positional operator for update has been around since 1.4 but for find projection it's new in 2.2

Answer (score 1):

When working with arrays Embedded to the Document, the best approach is the one suggested by Chien-Wei Huang.

I would just add another aggregation, with the [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) (in cases the document is very long, you may not want to retrieve all its content, only the array elements) Operator.

Now the command would look like:

```
db.test.aggregate({$match:{name:"record"}}, 
{$unwind:"$items"}, 
{$match {"items.histPrices":[10, 12]}}, 
{$group: {_id: "$_id",items: {$push: "$items"}}});)
```

If you are interested to **return only one element from the array in each collection**, then you should use [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) instead

The same kind of issue solved here:
[MongoDB Retrieve a subset of an array in a collection by specifying two fields which should match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194294/mongodb-retrieve-a-subset-of-an-array-in-a-collection-by-specifying-two-fields-w/20152599#20152599)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.test.aggregate({$unwind:"$items"}, {$match:{"items.histPrices":[10, 12]}})
```

But I don't know whether the performance would be OK. You have to verify it with your data.

[The usage of $unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_unwind)

If you want add some filter condition like `name="record"`, just add another `$march` at first, ex:

```
db.test.aggregate({$match:{name:"record"}}, {$unwind:"$items"}, {$match:{"items.histPrices":[10, 12]}})
```

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828
- [Get particular element from mongoDB array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562485/get-particular-element-from-mongodb-array)
- [MongoDB query to retrieve one array value by a value in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557508/mongodb-query-to-retrieve-one-array-value-by-a-value-in-the-array)

Comment: First one failed with JS Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'db.test.aggregate({$unwind:'$items'},{$match:{'items.histPrices':[10,12]}})')

Comment: I see..your query is based around mongodb 2.2's aggregation framework? I was on a 2.1.x stack so this apparently didn't work.

Comment: Yes, my mongodb version is 2.2.

Comment: @ttback 2.1.x are unstable development releases; you should upgrade to 2.2 if at all possible.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Turns out the prod server has 2.0.7. Upgrade will happen next week, which I'm very happy about. I will try this on my local env and see what happens.

Comment: Any ideas on how to check the performance of these three solutions?

Comment: You can insert many records(maybe about 10000) in the collection. Then use each method with a loop running 100000 times and measure the time. I think the performance of RameshVel's solution will be better than using aggregation.